# Adding active class in menu only works on first page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have nav links that become active once they come into the window. I need to implement this on three separate pages on my website but the following scripts only work for the first page.

```
var services_refresh = function () {
    // do stuff
    console.log('Stopped Scrolling');

    if ($('#ct_scans.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#ct_scans"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#xray.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#xray"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#fluoroscopy.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#fluoroscopy"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#mri.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#mri"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#neuroimaging.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#neuroimaging"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#nuclear_medicine.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#nuclear_medicine"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#ultrasound.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#ultrasound"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#mammography.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#mammography"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#breast_ultrasound.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#breast_ultrasound"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#breast_biopsy.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#breast_biopsy"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#breast_mri.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#breast_mri"]').addClass('active');

    } else if ($('#osteoporosis.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#our_services_sub_sections li a[href="#osteoporosis"]').addClass('active');
    }
};
```

Here is my HTML for the first page that works:

```
 <ul id="our_services_sub_sections" class="diagnostic_images">

    <li><a class="scroll active" href="#ct_scans">CT Scans</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#xray">X-Ray</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#fluoroscopy">Fluoroscopy</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#mri">MRI</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#neuroimaging">Neuroimaging</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#nuclear_medicine">Nuclear Medicine</a></li>
    <li><a class="scroll" href="#ultrasound">Ultrasound</a></li>

 </ul>
```

Here is my HTML for the second page which does not work:

```
<ul id="our_services_sub_sections" class="womens_imaging">

  <li><a class="scroll active" href="#mammography">Mammography</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#breast_ultrasound">Breast Ultrasound</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#breast_biopsy">Breast Biopsy</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll" href="#breast_mri">Breast MRI</a></li>
  <li><a class="scroll osteo" href="#osteoporosis">Osteoporosis<br />Evaluation (DEXA)</a></li>

</ul>
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: do you have duplicate IDs in those 2 pages?

Comment: Are you sure the JS is being included/called on the subsequent pages?

Comment: Are you calling your `services_refresh()` function again when the second page gets in the window? Or do you only call it once?

Comment: @Krishna the only duplicate ID is the ul `our_services_sub_sections` but I have also tried to make those ID references in the JS script `#our_services_sub_sections.diagnostic_images` and `#our_services_sub_sections.womens_imaging` which didn't work either

Comment: @Chris you may be on to something. But I'm not sure how to call it again on the other page?

Comment: @FastTrack you may be on to something. But I'm not sure how to call it again on the other page?

Comment: The best method is to save the javascript in an external file. and then link to it from every file that requires the script. <script src="js/common.js"></script> for example.

Comment: @rileychuggins I would put your function in a separate file and include it at the top of each page with a `<script>` tag like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="folder/fileName.js"></script>`. Then call the function on each page after it's included.

Comment: @lharby all of my scripts and stylesheets are linked an a header.php which is included on every page.

Comment: Well that makes it very easy then. Treat this the same way. Do you mean that you are doing this and the script is still not working? It could be the duplicate id issue. The js will target the first element it finds with that id. You might want to use classes. @rileychuggins

Comment: @FastTrack my scripts are in a separate file and included in the top of my header.php which is included on each page along with my stylesheets. Could this be creating an error - Should I name each page ID separately?

Comment: @lharby I have also used their classes in the javascript function `#our_services_sub_sections.diagnostic_images and #our_services_sub_sections.womens_imaging` which still only worked on the first page

Comment: Is your code online somewhere?

Comment: @lharby [link](http://easternrad.faulkneradvertising.com/services.php)

Comment: @rileychuggins check my answer below - does that work for you?

Comment: Weird it looks like the function is working. When I click on Mammography, it adds the class active to the list item, but I cannot see the white arrow being updated. Hang on.

Comment: OK, I could be wrong but it looks as though are adding the active class to both the ul li, and the ul li a, is this correct, should the class apply to both, or only one?

Comment: @lharby mammography starts with a class of active and as you scroll down it should switch the active class that's where I'm having the problem

Comment: @lharby it should only be adding the class to ul li a thats what it shows for mine on chrome

Comment: I will see if I can make a jsfiddle later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve my problem.

Here is an example of what I had to do for each of the three pages:

```
var services_refresh = function () { 

if($('#firstpage.anchor').length != 0) {

  if($('#firstpage.anchor').visible()) {

       $('#nav_sub_section li a').removeClass('active');

       $('#nav_sub_section li a[href="#firstpage"]').addClass('active');

   }

} else if($('#secondpage.anchor').length != 0) {

    if($('#secondpage.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#nav_sub_section li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#nav_sub_section li a[href="#secondpage"]').addClass('active');

    }

} else if($('#thirdpage.anchor').length != 0) {

    if($('#thirdpage.anchor').visible()) {

        $('#nav_sub_section li a').removeClass('active');

        $('#nav_sub_section li a[href="#thirdpage"]').addClass('active');

    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are including the function on every page using an include, you probably need to call the function each time a page is loaded.

So, inside each page (just after the opening `<body>` tag) run your function from inside a JS script block like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //call the function
    services_refresh();
</script>
```

Also, instead of making your function a variable - I would just make it a plain function like so:

```
function services_refresh(){
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatley, this doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @rileychuggins try altering your function like I showed above. Don't set it to a variable - make it stand on it's own, without a variable declaration. Then try to call it on each page like I showed.

Comment: if I use `function services_refresh(){ }` there is no change.